# Checking for duplicates before inserting a record in Document databases

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, nosql

How do I check for existing documents with duplicate User ID before inserting a document? In the RDBMS world, I would generally have a unique constraint to ensure that there are no duplicates in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase, there is a unique constraint on what is in effect the primary key of the document: its ID (or key) must indeed be unique.

Latest versions of most SDKs (eg for Java it's 2.2.0) now have an `exist` operation that can be used to check if a particular key is stored. Otherwise you have operations like `

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way to introduce composite indexes? Additionally, can I have unique on multiple keys?

Comment: Not really, this is a document nosql store... However with cb4.0 the N1QL query language was introduced, in which you can create indexes on several fields of your Json. No unique constraint concept in couchbase.